# Magento - Custom options do not update price of configurable product

Tags: php, magento

In Magento 1.9 I've created configurable product with 2 associated products. In *Super product attributes configuration* I set-up fixed price difference like for any other configurable product. Later on I created a Custom Option called **Gift Wrap** (checkbox, fixed price, sku: gift-wrap) for the main configurable product.

When selecting the checkbox in front-end and adding item to the shopping cart the  checkout page `/checkout/cart/` shows price without custom option! Why Gift Wrap price was not summed with Configurable product price?

Answer (score 1):

We managed to find the root of the problem. Magento's Configurable product works just fine with Custom Option. We had installed `FME_Pricecalcultor` there are bugs in `FME_Pricecalcultor_Model_Observer` observer model.